# PHP SQL not showing output for long text

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a student who is currently doing android project. I am learning how to get data from php. The code working fine in phpmyadmin where required data is shown, but when it comes to google or postman, it shown blank.

SQL:

```
// if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
//  $quest_id = $_POST['quest_id'];
// }

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT quest, quest_mark, subquest1, subquest2, subquest3, subquest4, subquest5 
        FROM subjectivequest 
        WHERE subjective_id='34' ORDER BY id";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,
    array(
        'quest'=>$row[0],
        'quest_mark'=>$row[1],
        'subquest1'=>$row[2],
        'subquest2'=>$row[3],
        'subquest3'=>$row[4],
        'subquest4'=>$row[5],
        'subquest5'=>$row[6]
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($conn);
```

It store subjective questions with subquestions and mark. When i tried with

```
"SELECT quest_mark, subquest1, subquest2, subquest3, subquest4, subquest5 
FROM subjectivequest 
WHERE subjective_id='34' ORDER BY id",
```

it works fine. However, when i added `quest`, the output become blank. May I know how can I solve this problem as the data is needed for implementing my project?

phpmyadmin: [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjIL1.png)

Comment: Your data is already in an array called `$row`, why are you pushing the results to a new array? Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Try to use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the firstline to see potential warnings and errors.

Comment: RE: My Edit: It help s if we can read the query without having to scroll right

Comment: `$result[] = $row;` Is a whole lot simpler than an `array_push()` mentioning all the 7 columns and does the same thing

Comment: Thx for reply. I follow the tutorial from https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/. Since it working fine for other data retrieve, so I didn't look deep into it.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried with code but it shows nothing at all. Whenever I remove the `quest`, it shows output without any errors.

Comment: Did you also look in your PHP Error log?

Comment: Did you mean PHP(php_error_log)? I clicked on it, it prompt "system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Try running the script directly from the browser (not using the android app) Do you get anything on the output then?

Comment: Ya, I am running the query on localhost with google before working on android. The page shows empty, same goes to postman. I tried to search for solution and I not really sure is it the text for the `quest` is too long in the database or not.

Comment: I have tried on set the `quest` with just one word, it shows output. It seems the data inside `quest` is too long, is there anyway to fix this?